# Access to Reporting services Reports?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, reporting-services

I have problem with reporting services. mostly about security and security configure.
so the biggest problem I've got is :

> How access to reporting services (mean reports) for none certificated computer(user)?

Let me explain about this question, I have windows-app and web-app, both of them use reporting services as base for reports. But when want use these app in none-domain-network. this problem occur. (for example, web-app users have access to web-app via internet it's Ridiculous to make them in member of domain)

> **Additional Info:**
>   I'm use Server mode in report viewer control. I have address uri of reporting service and also I put all reports into the same directory in reporting. when I want execute any report in web or win application, just send the report name to sightly form or page (also set report server uri and report path and after setting report path call refresh method and even set parameter for some reports).
>
> I also find something call **local report in report viewer control** but its seems odd cuz you must define **data-source** in your project and even **attach report-file** to solution and then can use report !!!

Answer (score 0):

Change your web application to use a single reporting domain account in your code to generate your reports. Is that possible?

Comment: just scroll to the bottom on that site to see the answers.. they trick you usually : )

Comment: I removed the link - the original question still stands though - are you generating the reports in your app via a call (in code)? If so you can just use a single domain account then to generate your reports.